# Как правильно использовать crossOrigin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть скрипт который берет изображение с другого сайта переделывает его в base66, и запихивает в localStorage. Для того чтоб, взять изображение с такого сайта как википедия достаточно указать атрибут crossOrigin="*" . Я так понимаю crossOrigin, это разрешение на использование контента этого сайта. А как разрешать доступ к картинкам для одного из своих сайтов. Что мне нужно поставить в крос орджин какую-то свою метку ?

Для наглядности привожу скрипт:

```html
<img id="bannerImg" class="image" crossOrigin="*" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Proton-K-Zarya.jpg/800px-Proton-K-Zarya.jpg" />
<img id="tableBanner" class="image" crossOrigin="*" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Richard_of_Shrewsbury%2C_1._Duke_of_York.jpg?download" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
  if (images.length > 0) {
    // в Storage
    var dataArray = [];
    for (var i = 0, itemsLength = images.length; i < itemsLength; i++) {
      dataArray.push({
        img: getBase64Image(images[i]),
        id: images[i].id || ''
      });
    }
    localStorage.setItem("imagesData", JSON.stringify(dataArray));

    //из Storage
    var storageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('imagesData'));
    if (Array.isArray(storageArray)) {
      storageArray.map(function(dataImage) {
        var element = document.getElementById(dataImage.id);
        if (element) {
          element.src = "data:image/png;base64," + dataImage.img;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
  }

});
```

P.S. доступ к изображением должен получить не другой сервер а клиентский скрипт...(браузер)

Comment: А что бы отправить, надо прикреплять дополнительный `header` с параметром `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` [wikipedia: cors](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: @Alex Krass, а если я укажу Allow-Origin: startLoad , и укажу на клиенте crossOrigin="startLoad ", то доступ к картинкам получит , только мой клиентский скрипт . Правильно ли я понимаю ?

Comment: Указывать вы должны домен, а не просто строчку любую. По факту только сервер определяет домены, которые могут получить доступ к содержимому. От клиента строка нужна только для того, что бы попросить этот доступ у браузера, если разрешение от сервера есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сервер www.b.com хочет разрешить получение данных с www.a.com то в ответе сервера будет присутствовать строчка:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.a.com
```

Для нескольких доментов их можно указать через пробел:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.a.com http://www.b.com http://www.c.com
```

Comment: а если запрос на получение изображения делает не сервер, а клиентский скрипт(браузер) ?